# Will applications compiled with Visual Basic 5 run on Vista or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, vb5

The subject says it all...

I am not, however, asking if the VB5 IDE will install and run on Vista/Windows 7 - just the project output.

Thanks

[UPDATE]

I found some more information that seems to show that not only will VB5 apps run under Windows 7 (x64) - but the IDE does too.
http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-619859.html

[UPDATE]

Thanks Jay, It makes sense that these programs wont run on x64 (any O/S) - I don't know how the vbforums member got it running on Win7 x64.

Comment: VB5 programs are 16-bit modules. They won't directly run under 64-bit version of Windows. They'll need a 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: @Jay - not even under WOW64? Good info to know, but let's hear from some more people too - what about 32-bit Vista/7?

Comment: Windows x64 has dropped support to run 16-bit modules. These includes 16-bit Windows and DOS programs. Technically, the subsystem to support them are no longer exists. *All* 32-bit Windows can still run them. Note: I have no info regarding this matter for 32-bit version of Window 8 (if such edition exists).

Comment: @Adam: It's well documented that **64-bit** Windows dropped support for 16-bit applications (as Jay has already told you). As far as "what about 32-bit Vista?", it's a **32-bit** operating system (thus the **32-bit** in the name), and therefore supports 16-bit applications like those written in VB5.

Comment: @Ken - Jay's response was appreciated and rules out x64. 'They'll need a 32-bit version of Windows' is not a comprehensive and timeless statement, so I responded to leave the question open to Jay and the community for clarification. Jay has done this. Good work Jay - if you post your response as an answer rather than a comment, I can approve it.

Comment: @Adam: What part of "They'll need a 32-bit version of Windows" is unclear? It clearly rules in Win32. ????

Comment: @Ken - yes it does rule in 32-bit versions. All 32-bit versions. Including Windows 8 for example - but I'm not just going to ass-ume that it will work on Windows 8. The overall discussion has more value with Jay's very explicit clarification (and any more posts that people may make with actual experiences). That is all - I had no interest in upsetting you. Good work everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. I have several applications(.exe files) compiled with VB5, which I can run on my 64 Bit W7 machine without any extra setting.